# Reading a file into a list?

Tags: java, list, bufferedreader, hashset

this problem cannot be solved this time, due to major errors in the code which need to be corrected first before submitting the question.

Comment: Hm. Now it's a mess of a question -- answers unrelated to the new text of the question. Maybe now delete the whole thing, or at least leave the old text as context for the answers? Your question may get closed if left in this state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
if (result = true)
```

do

```
if (result)
```

Also, instead of:

```
for (int index = 0; index < lineList.size() - 1; index =+2)
```

do

```
for (int index = 0; index < lineList.size(); index +=2)
```

**Edited: Two issues on your for statement:**

1. `index < lineList.size() - 1` will not hit the last item. Either remove `- 1` or change `<` for `<=`
2. Index does not increment its value. Change `index =+2` for `index +=2`.

Answer (score 0):

One obvious bug I could find was:

```
if (result = true)
```

which should be:

```
if (result == true)
```

Answer (score 0):

One problem is here:

```
 if (result = true)
```

You probably meant to write:

```
 if (result == true)
```

A better way to write this check is:

```
 if (result)
```

There *might* also be an off-by-one bug in `index < lineList.size() - 1`. If the file contains an odd number of lines, your current code will disregard the last line. I say *might* since it's not entirely clear what you expect to happen in this case.

Finally, the whole thing can be implemented with a single loop and without the list (i.e. just with the set).

Comment: seriously? copying my answer?

Answer (score 0):

You have a section with two errors. Compare with my sample:

```
for (int index = 0; index < lineList.size() - 1; index += 2)
  if (usr.add(list.get(index))) System.out.println(list.get(index));
```

Or, in another idiom:

```
boolean take = true;
for (String line : lineList) {
  if (take) usr.add(line);
  take = !take;
}
```